# Knex Postgres Heroku - Error: Unable to Acquire Connection

Tags: postgresql, heroku, knex.js

I'm aware of the post and similar question here([Knex Migration Postgres Heroku - Error: Unable to Acquire Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41633344/knex-migration-postgres-heroku-error-unable-to-acquire-connection)) I'm not sure what is missing in my .env I just basically have the following line in there : HOST= http://localhost:3000.

My knexfile:

```
module.exports = {

  development: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: 'postgres://localhost/eka_dev',
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  },

  test: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: 'postgres://localhost/eka_test',
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  },

  production: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  }
};
```

Knex file:

```
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const knexConfig = require('./knexfile')[environment];
const knex = require('knex')(knexConfig);

module.exports = knex;
```

app.js file:

```
const express= require('express');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');
const usersRoute = require('./routes/users');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  require('dotenv').config();
}

const allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
  if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
    res.send(200);
  } else {
    next();
  }
};

app.use(allowCrossDomain);

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.use('/api', usersRoute);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Express server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `NODE_ENV=production` environment variable in your Heroku setup and check what is the contents of `DATABASE_URL`variable.